# select distinct column field and total sum for it in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following table:

```
topic_id(unique)  forum_id   forum_views

1002                1885         5
1003                1893         2
1004                1885         3
1005                1892         6
```

How can i get output like this: (unique forum_id with total forum views from above table)

```
forum_id    forum_views
1885           8
1893           2
1892           6
```

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.

This is what i am trying:

> select distinct forum_id, sum(topic_views) from table_name

Comment: you need to group by the forum_id

Comment: add ...group by forum_id

Answer (score 9):

```
select forum_id, 
       sum(forum_views) as forum_views
from jforum_topics
group by forum_id
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this query `select forum_id, sum(distinct forum_views) from table group by forum_id;`

In this query **sum distinct** will do the sum of distinct value and do the grouping by the desired column.

If you want sum of all the values irrespective of distinctness then simply use  `sum(forum_views)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select forum_id, sum(forum_views) as sum from table_name group by forum_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `GROUP BY` to specify over which rows you wish the `SUM` applied to;

```
select forum_id, sum(topic_views) from jforum_topics 
group by forum_id 
order by forum_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select forum_id, sum(topic_views) 
from jforum_topics
group by forum_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select forum_id, sum(topic_views) from jforum_topics group by forum_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,it will sum your forum_views regarding to forum_id .

```
SELECT forum_id
     , SUM(forum_views)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY forum_id
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be

```
  select id2,sum(id3) from supportContacts group by id2
```

See this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b9e7/3

Answer (score 0):

You may also try out with:

```
select distinct forum_id, sum(topic_views) 
from jforum_topics
group by forum_id
```