# How to Count data with different column variables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to ask about how to count the number of data with several different variables in a column, for example I have data like this:

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbQz.png)

how to calculate the quantity of mangoes and apples that have been taken?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582626/select-distinct-column-field-and-total-sum-for-it-in-mysql

Comment: That's the input; what's the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by clause and then can apply sum function over it.

```
Select Item, Sum(Quantity) from TableName group by Item;
```

and to rename the new column you can use as

```
Select Item, Sum(Quantity) as 'Total' from TableName group by Item;
```

to get only quantity of mangoes and apples you can use where clause

```
Select Item, Sum(Quantity) as 'Total' from TableName where Item in ('Apple', 'Mango') group by Item;
```